# Area 51 - 51 Character Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

The type as you search for Area 51 has a nice little quirk and at 51 characters it sends you to a blank page. Not sure if this is intentional or not (meant to be funny, maybe?).

Comment: Definitely meant to be funny.  Nice catch :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed now. There was a bug in our trim-and-append-ellipsis method for one-word queries over 50 characters long.

Comment: Ah, young padawan, you have much to learn. If you have a 51-character bug on a site called Area 51, *it's a feature*. Even if it's unplanned.